# Как избежать спама в отзывах сайта woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины, спам

На сайт созданном на wordpress + woocommerce, приходит много спама в обзоры товаров:
https://evroflag.by/product/flagi-rascvechivaniya
Очень много спама в комментарии к товарам.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста. Как избежать спама.
Поставить ReCaptcha? Как это сделать?
Буду благодарен за подробности.

Comment: Масса плагинов должна быть. Хотя бы [вот](https://woocommerce.com/products/recaptcha-for-woocommerce/)

Answer (score 0):

Нужно поставить и настроить антиспамовский плагин.

Только не капчи (даже "невидимые" - зло). Есть масса нормальных плагинов, использующих человечные методы - honeypot, Nonce, timeout

Например [La Sentinelle antispam](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/la-sentinelle-antispam/) сочетает все эти методы. А также имеет другие полезные плюшки.